# Excel - Sheet Fields in FileName

Tags: excel, vba

I have a check request spreadsheet XLTX template I use and it would be really convenient to run a macro or something similar and have 2 of the fields in the sheet be inserted into the filename when I save it.

For example, this is the template filename - Check Request - NAME - Invoice #

I'd love to name 2 fields in the sheet NAME and Invoice # and have those inserted into the filename when I save it - any thoughts on how to do that? I used to be quite adept at VB and Office Macros but Python is more my thing now.

Comment: What do you mean by "field"? A named range?

Comment: Yes, either a named range or inserting a VBA object in dev mode

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub save_file()

Dim filename As String
Dim range_1 As String
Dim range_2 As String
Dim file_extension As String

file_extension = ".xlsm"

range_1 = Sheets("NAME").Range("Name_range").Value
range_2 = Sheets("Invoice #").Range("Invoice_range").Value

'Get the filename based on the given ranges
filename = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, file_extension, "") & "_" & range_1 & "_" & range_2 & file_extension

'Save file in the same folder as the template, bit with custom name
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & filename)

End Sub
```

I've used 2 named ranges: Name_range is on sheet NAME and Invoice_range is on sheet Invoice #. This should work as intended, but make sure you change the file extension, the name of the ranges and the name of the sheets to work with your workbook.